# How to save data in the database using codeigniter?

Tags: database, codeigniter-3

```
public function registration_insert($data) {
    //$this->db->trans_start();
    //echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);die;

// Query to check whether username already exist or not
$condition = "user_name =" . "'" . $data['user_name'] . "'";
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('user_login');
$this->db->where($condition);
$this->db->limit(1);
$query = $this->db->get();
// Query to insert data in database
$this->db->insert('user_login', $data);
if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
return true;
}
```

This is my program. It is not executing this code. I want to store the data in the database. Explicitly, with `print_r()`, it is posting the data but it is not storing it in the database and it is showing error.

Comment: Make sure about the column_name mention in `$data` array and table are same.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i want to check your $data variable , if $data is not an object that have the sames attribute name like your  database table column that will give you a problem.

I mean, for exemple if  your user_login table have tow column (id , user_name), you should have in the $data object the same name of attributes

and to verify if your  query work correctly just your  code will be like this :

```
$q = $this->db->insert('user_login', $data);
 if ($q) {
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```